# JQuery on hover doesn't work and runs instantly after loading page

Tags: jquery, html, css, onhover

i wanted to change element color by hovering, but when i run the page, it instantly triggers these functions, is there a way to stop it from doing so? It can be seen when reloading pages.

https://jsfiddle.net/9ae0ez2y/

```
function colorIn(primary){
    $("header").css("background-color", primary);
    $(".button").css("background-color", primary);
}

function colorOut(secondary){
    $("header").css("background-color", secondary);
    $(".button").css("background-color", secondary);
}
$("#variables").hover(colorIn("#ffffff"), colorOut("#111111"));
```

Comment: Just want to note that your colorIn and colorOut functions are identical. You can use the same function in both places with a different variable.

Answer (score 4):

Change your hover statement to:

```
$("#variables").hover(function() {
  colorIn("#ffffff")
}, function() {
  colorOut("#111111")
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9ae0ez2y/1/)**

The way you write it you're calling the functions immediately

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the functions, you are calling them in the `hover`, you should do something like this,

```
$("#variables").hover(colorIn.bind(null, "#ffffff"), colorOut.bind(null, "#111111"));
```